# Android: different theme when using PopupWindow in Listview

Tags: android

I've got a custom listview inside a fragment that inflates a `PopupWindow` whenever an message is clicked.

However I can't seem to figure out why the buttons in the list-view header are using a different theme/style than the normal rows in the listview. Can someone please care to explain?

#### List-view item:

[image: image 1]

#### List-view header:

[image: image 2]

#### This is how i inflate the toolbar:

```
popup = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_tool, null, false));
popup.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);

Rect location = locateView(v);
popup.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location.left, location.top - 200);
```

#### QuestionFragment.java

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);

        final ListView messages = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.messages);
        messages.setDivider(null);

        // Add question (header)
        View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_question, null);

        MessageModel messageItem = new MessageModel();
        messageItem.message = question.getQuestion();
        messageItem.id = question.getId();
        messageItem.gender = question.getGender();
        messageItem.name = question.getName();

        LinearLayout messageBackground = (LinearLayout)headerView.findViewById(R.id.messageBackground);

        TextView message = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.question);
        int bgDrawable = (messageItem.gender > 1) ? R.drawable.bubble_red_left_states : R.drawable.bubble_blue_left_states;
        messageBackground.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), bgDrawable));

        messages.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                SingleInstancePopup.GetInstance().hidePopup();
            }
        });

        messageBackground.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Clicked on question");

                SingleInstancePopup popup = SingleInstancePopup.GetInstance();

                if(popup.getPopup() != null) {
                    popup.hidePopup();
                } else {
                    popup.showPopup(inflater, v);
                }

            }
        });

        message.setText(messageItem.message);

        messages.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false);

        // Add footer
        View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_footer, null);
        messages.addFooterView(footerView, null, false);

        messagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        messages.setAdapter(messagesAdapter);

        final Handler handler_ = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == UPDATE_UI) {

                    QuestionModel question = (QuestionModel) msg.obj;

                    for (AnswerModel answer : question.getAnswers()) {

                        MessageModel messageItem = new MessageModel();
                        messageItem.message = answer.getComment();
                        messageItem.id = answer.getId();
                        messageItem.gender = answer.getGender();
                        messageItem.name = answer.getName();
                        messageItem.reply = (answer.getParentId() > 0);

                        messagesAdapter.add(messageItem);
                    }

                    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) messages.findViewById(R.id.messagesProgress);
                    if (progress != null) {
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            try {
                QuestionModel q = QuestionModel.getById(question.getId());
                handler_.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler_, UPDATE_UI, q));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Failed to load question", e);
            }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

        return view;
    }
```

#### MessagesAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final MessageModel messageItem = this.getItem(position);

    View v;
    int bgDrawable;
    if(messageItem.reply) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_answer_reply, null, false);
        bgDrawable = (messageItem.gender > 1) ? R.drawable.bubble_red_right_states : R.drawable.bubble_blue_right_states;
    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_answer, null, false);
        bgDrawable = (messageItem.gender > 1) ? R.drawable.bubble_red_left_states : R.drawable.bubble_blue_left_states;
    }

    LinearLayout messageBackground = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.messageBackground);

    TextView message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.comment);

    messageBackground.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), bgDrawable));

    message.setText(messageItem.message);

    messageBackground.setClickable(true);

    messageBackground.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Pressing down on message");

            SingleInstancePopup popup = SingleInstancePopup.GetInstance();

            if(popup.getPopup() != null) {
                popup.hidePopup();
            } else {
                popup.showPopup(inflater, v);
            }

        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

Thanks!

- Simon

Comment: My assumption is that you use a different context in the second case (i.e. one that doesn't have a theme), but if you would post some could it would help clarifying the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **MessagesAdapter.java**, `inflater` doesn't have your activity's theme, that's why your buttons look different. Instead of getting the system inflater service, pass the activity's layout inflater to your adapter, like this:

**QuestionFragment.java**

```
messagesAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getLayoutInflater());
```

**MessagesAdapter.java**
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

```
public MessagesAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    super(context, 0);
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final MessageModel messageItem = this.getItem(position);

    View v;
    int bgDrawable;
    if (messageItem.reply) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_answer_reply, null, false);
        bgDrawable = (messageItem.gender > 1) ? R.drawable.bubble_red_right_states : R.drawable.bubble_blue_right_states;
    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_answer, null, false);
        bgDrawable = (messageItem.gender > 1) ? R.drawable.bubble_red_left_states : R.drawable.bubble_blue_left_states;
    }

    // .......

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly! 

Never thought much about passing along the inflater - so thank you very much for this! 

- Simon